# Lightning component : get the value of a field - error

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

In a lightning component I have a field displaying a value that I'd like to modify. So in the component I wrote the field like that :

```
<aura:attribute name="products" type="WrapperClass[]" />
  //some code
<aura:iteration items="{!v.products}" var="vCurrentProduct">
  //other code    
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" aura:id="inQuantity" value="{!vCurrentProduct.quantity}" change="{!c.update}"/>
  //other code 
</aura:iteration>
```

In the js file I wrote the `update` function, very simple for now, I'd just like to display in the console the new value of the field :

```
update : function(component, event, helper) {
     var action = component.find("inQuantity").get("v.value");
    console.log('new value : ' + action);
},
```

But when I change the value of the field I got this error :

> component.find(...).get is not a function

**EDIT**

I change the `update` function :

```
update : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action;
    for(var cmp in component.find("inQuantity")){
        action = cmp.get("v.value");
        console.log('new : ' + action);
    }
}
```

But I still get the error :

> cmp.get is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have multiple elements with same aura:I'd then component.find returns an array of components rather than a single component

You may want to loop over the result set and then use get function to retrieve each values .

Here is the correct syntax for the same for your client side controller

```
update : function(component, event, helper) {
    var output;
    for(var cmp in component.find("inQuantity")){
        console.log(component.find("inQuantity")[cmp]);
        output = component.find("inQuantity")[cmp].get("v.value");
        console.log(output);
    }
 }
```

Comment: But the `aura:id="inQuantity"` is unique in this component, so it should work ?

Comment: It's not since its inside iteration .There will be multiple input number tags with same aura:id

Comment: So I have to make a for loop inside the js file in which I put `component.find("inQuantity")` ?

Comment: No .The return of component.find will be looped over .

Comment: I change the function for the one I put in the edit of the question, but it still don't work...

Comment: What errors you get ? You can use console.log and log all you see to debug issues

Comment: I get the error I put in the edit of the question, I try to put some console.log but since it throw the error before I reach the debug I can see nothing

Comment: @dou you can try simple javascript loop as,

`var data = component.find("inQuantity").get("v.value");
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    console.log(data[i]);
}`

Comment: @thoriyas I try your way but since I got this error : "component.find(...).get is not a function" I can't see the log

Comment: @dou you should look this [link] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm#clientside) you can get the single input value using `event.target.value`

Comment: @dou Added code snippets to help you .Avoid using keywords like action and update in your variable names that may lead to some conflicts .

Comment: @thoriyas We can read attribute value as well and need not look for browser events for these simple use cases